# How to generate an input file for diehard test?

Tags: java

I've been trying to create an input file specifically for ASC2BIN.exe and it says:

```
You must first create the ascii file.  To do that,
generate your 32-bit integers and write them to a file,
in hex format, 80 characters (ten 32-bit integers) per
line.
```

So I understand that my RNG code will return an integer output (line by line in this case). So if I want to test it with Diehard, I need to convert them into the proper binary file. To do so, we have ASC2BIN.exe here which aims to create the binary file.

FOr example, my RNG outputs look like:

```
2
3
4
5
.
.
```

Follow to the message above of ACI2BIN.exe, I have to:

1, generate your 32-bit integers as follows

```
2 -> '00000000000000000000000000000010'
3 -> '00000000000000000000000000000011'
4 -> '00000000000000000000000000000100'
5 -> '00000000000000000000000000000101'
```

2, **write them to a file, in hex format?**

Does it seem I have to again convert the binary to hex format? If so, how can I do that? It sounds does not make sense to me. Or do I have to convert the file format to hex? I'm stuck here!

3, 80 characters (ten 32-bit integers) per line

Okay, it's clear that 234567891011 in 32-bit integers should be in the same line under the "hex format"?

Comment: Forget binary.  Convert your base-10 numbers directly to hex and add leading zeros as required.  One number per line.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm using java for the generator @PeterO.

Comment: Do you mean 10 integer numbers should be converted directly to hex? but what does it mean one number per line? does it against the requirement? @rossum

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  Ten number per line.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions mean to convert each 32 bit integer you have into a base-16 number (which will have eight base-16 digits), and write ten of these base-16 numbers in each line of the file. Here is an example (assuming `pw` is a `java.io.PrintWriter`):

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
   // Add a line break after every tenth number
   if (i > 0 && i % 10 == 0) {
      pw.println("");
   }
   // Write the next number in base 16, left-padded with zeros
   pw.printf("%08X", numbers[i]);
}
// Write the final line break
pw.println("");
```

Comment: thanks for the script, so a list of the 32 bit integer file becomes the input for the script, the script will convert 32-bit integer `(number[i])` to hex, each line contains 10 `number[i]` in hex format.